# Newbie having trouble with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have been studying Java by myself for a few weeks but I have become completely stuck in one challenge question I found online. I have thouroughly searched Google to see if anyone else asked it but I can't seem to find anything. Since I don't have any teachers, I was wondering if anyone on StackOverflow could help me out.

I am having an issue with one of my methods because it keeps failing my test cases and I'm not sure what exactly is making it go wrong.

Basically, if I input an array like [2, 8, 3, 9, 7], I want it to come out like [2, 3, 7, 8, 9]. However, with this poorly written method I have here, I keep getting the extra element at the beginning, which results in [2, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]. My specific goal with this method is to find and return an array that contains all values greater/equal to "high" and less than/equal to "low" , including duplicates. The length of this array should be the same as the # of elements in the 'range', hence the method name.

I just wanted to be properly directed towards the next step that I should be taking to eliminate this first element issue. I know that the code is probably awful and messy, so please bear with me.

Thank you; all help is appreciated!

```
public static int[] range(int[] a, int low, int high) {
  if (a == null || a.length == 0) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }

  int[] newArr = new int[0];
  if (low <= high) {
     if (a.length == 1 && low >= a[0] && high <= a[0]) {
        return a;
     }

     for (int i : a) {
        if (i >= low && i <= high) {
           int[] duplicate = new int[(a.length + 1)];
           int count = 0;
           for (int num : a) {
              duplicate[count] = num;
              count++;
           }
           duplicate[count] = i;
           return duplicate;
        }
     }
  }
  if (newArr.length > 1) {
     Arrays.sort(newArr);
  }
  return newArr;
```

}

Comment: You just need the `Arrays.sort` (and the `null` / `length` check). Why all of the other code?

Comment: *I'm not simply trying to sort the methods because the book is asking for something different*. Then what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Following @shmosel, what exactly are you trying to do ? Also, notice when you create the duplicate array, you allocate one more than needed, you should do new int[a.length];

Comment: so with input `[2, 8, 3, 9, 7]`, `low=2`, and `high=9`, it will return `[2, 3, 7, 8, 9]`?

Comment: @BagusTesa Unfortunately, it results with [2, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]. There is always that extra value in the beginning. If I passed in [1, 2, 3], it would result in [1, 1, 2, 3] for some reason.

Comment: @Ryu, i think the problem lies on your `duplicate`, i wonder if you could just iterate once to the source array (`[2, 8, 3, 9, 7]`) to find all `i >= low && i <= high`, put them into array. then sort them.. something like that a solution that i can think of -- i know it's inefficient, lol..

Comment: @Ryu please update your post to make it clear why simply using [`Array.sort(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) on your array does not work, because based on your text right now, that is literally the solution in a single line of code. Without additional details, this question has a trivial answer and will likely end up voted "closed" for not being clear on what the actual problem is.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Does "My specific goal with this method is to find and return an array that contains all values greater/equal to "high" and less than/equal to "low" , including duplicates. The length of this array should be the same as the # of elements in the 'range', hence the method name." not help either? Unless that is also all simply solved by Array.sort and I'm just simply delusional right now!

Comment: Unfortunately: not enough, no. It might help to explain in more detail what you mean with this explanation? For instance, if the input is `[3,75,2,8,5,1,4,9]` and that gets invoked for a low of 3 and a high of 75, then the only list that fits your description is `[3,75]`, which is *not* the same number of elements as the input, nor the same number of elements as the range (3,75), because there are 72 possible values in that range. So, can you be more specific, or can you give examples that help illustrate what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your specification correctly, you take an input array `a`, and two values `low` and  `high`.  You have to return a new array with only the elements between (inclusively) `low` and `high`.

You did not write anywhere in which order the elements should (apart than in your test case where the elements are sorted in ascending order).  Note: you can easily add the `sort()` method if you require it.

The main problem is that you have to determine the size of the returned array.  There are many ways to do it.  For simplicity, I'll do it in two loops.

```
public static int[] range( int[] a, int low, int high) {
  int result_size=0;
  int i, j;
  // determine result size
  for (i=0; i< a.length;i++) {
    if ((low <= a[i]) && (a[i] <= high)) result_size++;
  }
  // build the result array
  int [] result = new int[result_size];
  j = 0;   // destination
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if ((low <= a[i]) && (a[i] <= high)) {
      result[j] = a[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The second foor loop is already teaching me a lot more things about arrays and looping logic. This is exactly what I needed to clear up my code.